# Add User to project using his email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have projects which can have one `projectOwner` and multiple `projectMembers`. After creating my project, I want to be able to add users to this project.

Right now my problem is that I have to enter the `user_id` and `project_id` when creating a new `projectMember`. The form is expecting a `user_id` and `project_id` so how can I change that so that it takes an `email` and then finds the `user_id` related to it.

View:

```
<%= form_for([@project, @project.project_members.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
   <%= f.label :project_id %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :project_id %>
  </p>
  <p>
   <%= f.label :user_id %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :user_id %>
  </p>
  <p>
   <%= f.submit :Add, class: 'btn btn-info' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def create
  @project_member = ProjectMember.new(member_params)
  @project_member.save
end

private
  def member_params
    params.require(:project_member).permit(:user_id, :project_id)
  end
```

Model relation:

```
class  User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles
  has_many :projects, through: :roles
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end

class ProjectOwner < Role
end

class ProjectMember < Role
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_members
  has_many :members, class_name: "User", through: :project_members
  has_one  :project_owner
  has_many :owners, class_name: "User", through: :project_owner
end
```

Right now my routes look like this but I feel like this isnt the right way of doing it:

```
devise_for :users

resources :users do
  resources :projects
end

resources :projects do
  resources :project_members
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The form is expecting a user_id and project_id so how can I change
>   that so that it takes an email and then finds the user_id related to
>   it.

You can have an *input for the email in the form* and allow the *controller to do the rest*

```
<%= form_for([@project, @project.project_members.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
   <%= f.label :project_id %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :project_id %>
  </p>
  <p>
   <%= label_tag :email %><br>
   <%= email_field_tag :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
   <%= f.submit :Add, class: 'btn btn-info' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

In the controller, *find the user with the email*

```
def create
  @project_member = ProjectMember.new(member_params)
  @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
  @project_member.user_id = @user.id
  @project_member.save
end
```

Also, you don't need to provide `project_id` explicitly in the form. The `@project` in the form will give you the `project_id`. You just need to let the controller do the mapping

```
<%= form_for([@project, @project.project_members.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag :email %><br>
    <%= email_field_tag :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit :Add, class: 'btn btn-info' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

In the controller,

```
def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @project_member = @project.project_members.new(member_params)
  @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
  @project_member.user_id = @user.id
  @project_member.save
end
```

Comment: I'm getting `param is missing or the value is empty: project_member` on `params.require(:project_member).permit(:user_id, :project_id)` I'm using the second option where you don't provide the `project_id`

Comment: @CNuts Can you paste the `params` hash that is generated here?

Comment: Sure : `{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5eS6ZJ6c/WjoSZrTh6K7ehCS7Cgrj4nE0UmKeKv0LTJhse3PP93hHaeXXJHlBlBpjFqFXUjIZSni8OY/nxu1rw==", "email"=>"adam@email.com", "commit"=>"Add", "project_id"=>"1"}`

Comment: @CNuts Ok. I got it. You should either permit them without require like `params.permit(:user_id, :project_id)` or put `attr_accessor :email` in `ProjectMember` model and change `<%= email_field_tag :email %>` to `<%= f.email_field :email %>` so that the `params` will come under `:project_membet` key

Comment: They both work thank you so much :) which one is better to use?

Comment: @CNuts Can't say, but I would prefer the simplest one :)

Answer (score 0):

In your view, replace `user_id` with `user_email` field:

```
 <p>
   <%= f.label :user_email %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :user_email %>
  </p>
```

In controller, get the `email`

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:project_member][:user_email]) # find the user by email
  @project_member = ProjectMember.new(:project_id => params[:project_member][:project_id]) # create new project member with project id
  @project_member.users << user # assign user to newly created project member
  @project_member.save
end

private
  def member_params
    params.require(:project_member).permit(:user_email, :project_id)
  end
```

Hope it helps!

Note: **Please make sure if the User we find by email exists!**

Answer (score 0):

One way you achieve this is modifying your `member_params` as

```
def member_params
  member_params = params.require(:project_member).permit(:email, :project_id)
  if (user_id = User.find_by_email(member_params[:email]).try(:id)).present?
    member_params.merge!(user_id: user_id)
    member_params.permit!
  else
    # display error
  end
end
```

Or let your `params` be as it is

```
def member_params
  params.require(:project_member).permit(:email, :project_id)
end
```

in your controller,

```
def create
  @project_member = ProjectMember.build_by(member_params)
  if @project_member.save
    # success
  else
    # failure
  end
end
```

and model,

```
def self.build_by(params)
  project_member = self.new(params)
  project_member.user_id = User.find_by_email(params[:email]).try(:id)
end
```

I think, second option is more cleaner and logic moves to model..